# is this a gradle eclipse task bug or inconsistent on purpose?

Tags: gradle

So I have the following dependencies section in gradle

```
dependencies {    
    compile project(':sdi-master')
    compile fileTree(dir: '../webserver/lib', include: '*.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: '../webserver/play-1.2.4/framework/lib', include: '*.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: '../webserver/play-1.2.4/framework', include: 'play-*.jar')   
}
```

I also have a copy jars task like so

```
task deleteJars(type: Delete) {
    ext.collection = files { genLibDir.listFiles() }
    delete ext.collection
}
task copyJars(type: Copy) { 
    from(configurations.compile) {}
    into genLibDir
}
copyJars.dependsOn('deleteJars')
classes.dependsOn('copyJars')
```

Notice how it depends on sdi-master which then has ONE compile fileTree as well.  When I run copyJars, as expected, I get all the jars from the sdi-master as well copied into genLibDir.  When I run the eclipse task however, those jars do NOT show up in the .classpath file as I would expect so my project doesn't compile in eclipse.

Is this a gradle eclipse task bug I need to report or is this supposed to be the behavior(though it seems very inconsistent with the copy jars using configurations.compile.

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse understands transitive dependencies, so the dependencies of `sdi-master` will not (and should not) show up in the current project's `.classpath` file. They should just show up in `sdi-master`'s `.classpath` file and should be marked as `exported` there.